# App stop working on phone while working on all Emulators just one phone Huawei Nova 3e its working

Tags: android, emulation, mobile-phones

//getting such like logcat

Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'FinalizerDaemon'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 2) {adb30f2} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 2) {adb30f2})
        at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2695)
        at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:1112) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.evaluateJavascript(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:108) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:144) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zzfk(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:151) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:190) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:101) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.zzav(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:630) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.onDetachedFromWindow(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:434) 
        at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:18400) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3777) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3769) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5359) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5330) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:5261) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.zze.onDestroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:125) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbq.destroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:472) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbbo.destroy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:106) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbrc.finalize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@18.1.1:33) 
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250) 
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237) 
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

2019-08-08 19:51:22.250 5599-5629/com.iconicvines.finaldesign E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2019-08-08 19:51:22.250 5599-5629/com.iconicvines.finaldesign E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2019-08-08 19:51:22.962 5599-5629/com.iconicvines.finaldesign E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2019-08-08 19:51:23.036 5599-5629/com.iconicvines.finaldesign E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2019-08-08 19:51:27.244 1927-2052/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

Comment: You load webview on background thread instead main/UI thread so need to load webview in main thread

Comment: there is no webview in my app , i have  simple grid view

Comment: GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptor(mImageIds,this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int item_pos = mImageIds.get(position);

                ShowDialogBox(item_pos);
            }
        });

Comment: Can you tell when you get these error? e.g onClick, startActivity or other event